# Issue with deleting unactive users after a certain amount of time?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have this code to delete unactivated users after a certain amount of time has passed, in this case 7 days. Although the script doesn't seem to be working at all? Nothings happening ? When I remove the redirect links, it just shows a blank page. Tried echoing information, but nothing shows?

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'mysql.hostinger.co.uk';
$dbuser = 'u634727706_admin';
$dbpass = '';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$checkdate= "SELECT username, signup_date FROM users WHERE activated='0'";

$checkdate2 = mysql_query($checkdate);

while($checkdate3 = mysql_fetch_array($checkdate2)){
              $user = $checkdate3['username'].' ';
              $date = $checkdate3['signup_date'].' ';


$start = strtotime("$date");
// get today's date 
$today = strtotime("now");

// find difference (in seconds)
$time_elapsed = $today - $start; 

// get days elapsed 
$days_elapsed = $time_elapsed/86400;


if($days_elapsed >= 7){
    mysql_query ("DELETE FROM users WHERE username='$user'") or die ("update didn't work");
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://basecentre.co.uk/admin.php?page=5&cron=3">';
    exit();
}
}
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://basecentre.co.uk/admin.php?page=5">';
?>
```

Comment: You appended a space after `$user=$checkdate3['username']`, is it ok?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing it all in the database:

```
DELETE FROM users
    WHERE activated = '0' AND signup_date < now() - interval 7 day;
```